# Google+ Sign-In vs Google Sign-In Libraries [iOS 9 canOpenURL error]

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to understand the difference between

Google+ Sign-in library:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/

and Google Sign-in library:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

what's the difference?

In my app i'm currently using the Google+ library to retrive the user info,
but with iOS 9 i have few errors when attempting to call canOpenURL.

As said here:
[Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9 attempting to call canOpenURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl)

I added the reequired LSApplicationQueriesSchemes but doesn't solve the issue.

Seems that the last Google Sign-in library version solve the issue
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/31708157/2059307)
but i can't understand if I can swap the two libraries.

Comment: Hey. Did you find the solution or did you migrate to google sign in ?

Comment: @shannoga no solution, Google SignIn is more updated and does the same things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at the time of this writing, there's a big "This library has been deprecated" warning on the Google+ library [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/), so I guess my recommendation at this point would be to go with the Google Sign-in one.