# Google plus sign in crashes in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-plus, ios9

while sign in the app in ios 9 through the google plus account I got these message in my debug area. but it is working well for ios 8

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hasgplus4://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hasgplus4"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "googlechrome-x-callback:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome-x-callback"
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "googlechrome:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlechrome"
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Here might help your problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl