# canOpenURL issue for iOS 9 - Google+

Tags: ios, google-plus, ios9, url-scheme

With iOS 9 i am having issues using canOpenURL to open Google+ app specifically.

With the help of  [Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl) I have changed my **Info.plist** and added **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** as shown below

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>youtube</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent-google</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent-youtube</string>
    <string>com-google-gidconsent</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0</string>
    <string>googlechrome</string>
    <string>googlechrome-x-callback</string>
    <string>hasgplus4</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0</string>
    <string>com.google.gppconsent</string>
    <string>gplus</string>
</array>
```

All other apps like facebook yotube twitter are working fine but google plus wont open and shows the following error

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "gplus://" - error: "(null)"

is this some issue with Google+ app?

```
NSString *strURL =  @"gplus://";
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]])
        {
        }
        else
        {
            strURL = @"https://www.plus.google.com";
        }
```

Comment: try once in your device

Comment: check your g+ app installed or not?check this url schecme is supported or not http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html