# Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9.2 attempting to call canOpenURL

Tags: ios

I want to integrate my ios app with google plus. I followed all the steps from https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started  what still its show me a following error:

> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.547 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.548 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.549 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.550 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.551 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.552 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "hasgplus4://" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.645 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "googlechrome-x-callback:" - error: "(null)"
>
> 2016-02-29 15:04:17.646 LatestGooglePlus[74898:1497934] -canOpenURL:
>   failed for URL: "googlechrome:" - error: "(null)"

and i also  followed this  [Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9 attempting to call canOpenURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl) but still show me a same error please help me . thanks in advance .

Comment: you want to login through google account and get user details ?. Show some code.

Comment: yes i want to login through google account and get user detail .

Comment: is it working on other OS

Answer (score 0):

Add URL Scheme and configure the .plist file for iOS9.

Comment: I have no idea  how to add the URL  Scheme  and configure the .plist file  . please tell me how to add

Comment: Go to project Targets and then tab info and in URL Types and then add URL Schemes provided by Google.

Comment: what is the URL schemes. what can i give

Comment: its give me same error

Comment: You are integrating Google so you might have created app on Google.So from there you would have been download .plist configuration file so in that file you will find key that is to be added in URL Scheme.

Comment: still its give me same error

Comment: Have you disabled AppTransportSecurity?If not then please do that.

Comment: how to disables AppTransportSecurity

Comment: Please refer following link http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error