# Google play games sign in error on iOS

Tags: ios, google-play-games, google-signin

Hello I am trying to get google play games sign in on my iOS app.
I have installed the sdk manually and did everything as the Get started tutorial on the google website says.
But when I click the sign in button the app takes me to safari and I am getting those messages in the console:

```
2016-08-14 14:32:26.450 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.452 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.454 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.455 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.456 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent://" - error: "(null)"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.457 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hasgplus4://" - error: "(null)"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.486 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "googlechrome-x-callback:" - error: "(null)"
2016-08-14 14:32:26.487 פקודה![34477:5811630] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "googlechrome:" - error: "(null)"
```

even after I clicked allow on permissions it takes me back to my app but nothing happen even the func:

```
- (void)didFinishGamesSignInWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error)
    NSLog(@"GooglePlayGames finished signing in!");
    else
    NSLog(@"***Error signing in! %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
```

is not being called at all. please help

thats my code to sign in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
    [GPGManager sharedInstance].statusDelegate = self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;

    _currentlySigningIn = [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID :kClientID silently:YES];
}

# pragma mark -- GIDSignInUIDelegate methods

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",user);
}


# pragma mark -- GPGStatusDelegate methods

- (void)didFinishGamesSignInWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error)
    NSLog(@"GooglePlayGames finished signing in!");
    else
    NSLog(@"***Error signing in! %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
- (void)didFinishGamesSignOutWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Received an error while signing out %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     else
        NSLog(@"Signed out!");
}

- (IBAction)signInButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:kClientID silently:NO];
}

- (IBAction)signOutButtonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signOut];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found about *"This app is not allowed to query for scheme"*.

I think this is due to the changes to the new ios version, ios9.

Found this on this [blog](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes).

> The key bits regarding changes to URL schemes in iOS 9 is the Privacy
>   and Your Apps session, starting at around the 9 minute mark under the
>   heading “App Detection”.
>
> There are two URL-related methods available to apps on iOS that are
>   effected: canOpenURL and openURL. These are not new methods and the
>   methods themselves are not changing. As you might expect from the
>   names, “canOpenURL” returns a yes or no answer after checking if there
>   is any apps installed on the device that know how to handle a given
>   URL. “openURL” is used to actually launch the URL, which will
>   typically leave the app and open the URL in another app.

Check the code implementation in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl) for more info.