# Swift - Google Authentication Error

Tags: ios, swift, google-authentication

I am having an error in my google authentication function in IOS, I got the following exception, mentioned below:

```
  2016-08-28 16:58:59.776 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] Facebook Integration process completed...
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.789 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.790 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.790 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.3.0"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.791 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.2.0"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.792 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.google.gppconsent://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme com.google.gppconsent"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.792 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hasgplus4://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hasgplus4"
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.809 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] -[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde18f4cc30
    2016-08-28 16:58:59.813 TraitMLDS[3080:95638] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fde18f4cc30'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bd4d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103648deb objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bddd3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b23cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b238a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
        5   TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030c5203 -[GPPSignIn oauth2URLWithParams:] + 616
        6   TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030c52fe -[GPPSignIn doOAuthLoginWithParams:] + 109
        7   TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030c5994 -[GPPSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithParams:] + 77
        8   TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030c5bb1 -[GPPSignIn authenticateMaybeInteractively:withParams:] + 528
        9   TraitMLDS                           0x0000000103083715 _TFC9TraitMLDS14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 1221
        10  TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030837d2 _TToFC9TraitMLDS14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
        11  UIKit                               0x0000000104a68984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
        12  UIKit                               0x0000000104a68cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
        13  UIKit                               0x000000010493efb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
        14  UIKit                               0x000000010493f69d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
        15  UIKit                               0x0000000104951180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
        16  UIKit                               0x00000001048c5ed9 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
        17  UIKit                               0x00000001048cc568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
        18  UIKit                               0x00000001048c9714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
        19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108a9b8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
        20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108a9b741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
        21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108a9baca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103afa301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103af022c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103aef6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103aef0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
        26  UIKit                               0x00000001048c8f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
        27  UIKit                               0x00000001048cdf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
        28  TraitMLDS                           0x00000001030847e2 main + 114
        29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010715792d start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: How did you solve this? I am running into the same issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the short answer.

Have you tried this ?

> iOS 9 has introduced new changes to canOpenURL requiring the application to whitelist all the schemes it needs to query.
>
> [Google Sign-In crashes on iOS 9 attempting to call canOpenURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506865/google-sign-in-crashes-on-ios-9-attempting-to-call-canopenurl)

Comment: Thanks but when i call this "signIn?.authenticate()" my program is crashed. When I comment this line, my program works fine.I integrated Googleplus and FaceBook both in my project.I didn't find any solution yet for my this problem.

Comment: Could you update your question and provide the full stack trace of the error ?